# Distribution of votes per question

Tags: discussion

The user profile pages have a table with the (coarse) distribution of number of users grouped by reputation. Is there someplace I can find a table with the distribution of number of questions grouped by votes?

(Dynamic would be great, one-off for right now would be nice).

Comment: By grouped by votes, do you mean the count of questions for a particular score?  You could always write a SEDE query.  Or search for one.  This seems like the kind of query someone has already made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming by "number of questions grouped by votes" you mean the number of questions for each score.  I made this [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338787/count-of-questions-by-score).  The SEDE is updated once a week, so rerunning the query will be "dynamic" over weekly intervals.  For more on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer, see the [SEDE help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

```sql
select score, count(id)
from posts
where postTypeId = 1 --for questions
group by score
order by score desc
```

Results as of July 19, 2015 UTC 3:00:

```
+-------+---------+
| score | count   |
+-------+---------+
| 11369 |       1 |
|  7690 |       1 |
|  7115 |       1 |
|  5492 |       1 |
|  5209 |       1 |
|  4538 |       1 |
|  4529 |       1 |
|  4270 |       1 |
|  4255 |       1 |
|  4139 |       1 |
|  3933 |       1 |
|  3803 |       1 |
|  3621 |       1 |
|  3607 |       1 |
|  3585 |       1 |
|  3529 |       1 |
|  3426 |       1 |
|  3317 |       1 |
|  3273 |       1 |
|  3259 |       1 |
|  2913 |       1 |
|  2834 |       1 |
|  2790 |       1 |
|  2767 |       1 |
|  2707 |       1 |
|  2619 |       1 |
|  2591 |       1 |
|  2589 |       1 |
|  2585 |       1 |
|  2537 |       1 |
|  2458 |       1 |
|  2457 |       1 |
|  2354 |       1 |
|  2319 |       1 |
|  2310 |       1 |
|  2302 |       1 |
|  2299 |       1 |
|  2279 |       1 |
|  2262 |       1 |
|  2231 |       1 |
|  2224 |       1 |
|  2222 |       1 |
|  2202 |       1 |
|  2118 |       1 |
|  2113 |       1 |
|  2095 |       1 |
|  2084 |       1 |
|  2079 |       1 |
|  2037 |       1 |
|  2024 |       1 |
|  1993 |       1 |
|  1988 |       1 |
|  1936 |       1 |
|  1909 |       1 |
|  1874 |       1 |
|  1865 |       1 |
|  1821 |       1 |
|  1815 |       1 |
|  1801 |       1 |
|  1786 |       1 |
|  1785 |       1 |
|  1782 |       1 |
|  1772 |       1 |
|  1748 |       1 |
|  1743 |       1 |
|  1740 |       1 |
|  1737 |       1 |
|  1712 |       1 |
|  1702 |       1 |
|  1691 |       1 |
|  1675 |       1 |
|  1652 |       1 |
|  1625 |       1 |
|  1608 |       1 |
|  1607 |       1 |
|  1601 |       1 |
|  1584 |       1 |
|  1573 |       1 |
|  1565 |       1 |
|  1560 |       1 |
|  1557 |       1 |
|  1556 |       1 |
|  1548 |       1 |
|  1544 |       1 |
|  1523 |       1 |
|  1522 |       1 |
|  1517 |       1 |
|  1514 |       1 |
|  1478 |       1 |
|  1452 |       1 |
|  1442 |       1 |
|  1440 |       1 |
|  1432 |       1 |
|  1425 |       1 |
|  1422 |       1 |
|  1419 |       2 |
|  1410 |       1 |
|  1394 |       1 |
|  1387 |       1 |
|  1383 |       1 |
|  1380 |       1 |
|  1379 |       1 |
|  1376 |       1 |
|  1373 |       1 |
|  1353 |       1 |
|  1346 |       1 |
|  1342 |       1 |
|  1341 |       1 |
|  1326 |       1 |
|  1321 |       1 |
|  1318 |       2 |
|  1313 |       1 |
|  1297 |       1 |
|  1296 |       1 |
|  1293 |       1 |
|  1291 |       2 |
|  1286 |       1 |
|  1279 |       1 |
|  1275 |       1 |
|  1269 |       1 |
|  1267 |       1 |
|  1265 |       1 |
|  1261 |       2 |
|  1260 |       1 |
|  1258 |       1 |
|  1256 |       1 |
|  1255 |       1 |
|  1243 |       1 |
|  1240 |       2 |
|  1229 |       1 |
|  1228 |       1 |
|  1214 |       1 |
|  1212 |       1 |
|  1210 |       1 |
|  1209 |       1 |
|  1203 |       1 |
|  1194 |       1 |
|  1193 |       1 |
|  1178 |       2 |
|  1177 |       2 |
|  1175 |       1 |
|  1171 |       1 |
|  1168 |       1 |
|  1167 |       2 |
|  1165 |       1 |
|  1164 |       1 |
|  1163 |       1 |
|  1148 |       2 |
|  1147 |       1 |
|  1141 |       1 |
|  1138 |       1 |
|  1137 |       1 |
|  1133 |       1 |
|  1130 |       1 |
|  1129 |       1 |
|  1127 |       1 |
|  1125 |       1 |
|  1118 |       1 |
|  1113 |       1 |
|  1109 |       1 |
|  1102 |       1 |
|  1098 |       1 |
|  1089 |       1 |
|  1086 |       1 |
|  1073 |       1 |
|  1069 |       1 |
|  1067 |       2 |
|  1062 |       1 |
|  1061 |       2 |
|  1058 |       2 |
|  1052 |       1 |
|  1049 |       1 |
|  1045 |       2 |
|  1044 |       1 |
|  1043 |       1 |
|  1042 |       1 |
|  1038 |       1 |
|  1037 |       1 |
|  1036 |       1 |
|  1034 |       1 |
|  1032 |       3 |
|  1027 |       1 |
|  1026 |       1 |
|  1025 |       1 |
|  1022 |       1 |
|  1020 |       1 |
|  1019 |       3 |
|  1010 |       2 |
|  1005 |       1 |
|  1004 |       1 |
|  1002 |       1 |
|  1000 |       2 |
|   999 |       1 |
|   997 |       1 |
|   995 |       2 |
|   994 |       1 |
|   993 |       1 |
|   990 |       1 |
|   980 |       1 |
|   976 |       1 |
|   975 |       2 |
|   973 |       1 |
|   972 |       1 |
|   970 |       1 |
|   969 |       2 |
|   960 |       1 |
|   956 |       1 |
|   952 |       1 |
|   944 |       1 |
|   940 |       1 |
|   939 |       1 |
|   937 |       1 |
|   936 |       3 |
|   935 |       1 |
|   931 |       1 |
|   929 |       2 |
|   928 |       1 |
|   924 |       1 |
|   923 |       1 |
|   922 |       1 |
|   921 |       2 |
|   920 |       1 |
|   919 |       1 |
|   917 |       1 |
|   904 |       2 |
|   900 |       1 |
|   897 |       1 |
|   895 |       1 |
|   894 |       2 |
|   892 |       1 |
|   891 |       2 |
|   888 |       1 |
|   887 |       1 |
|   886 |       1 |
|   879 |       2 |
|   878 |       2 |
|   877 |       1 |
|   874 |       1 |
|   873 |       1 |
|   871 |       1 |
|   869 |       2 |
|   868 |       1 |
|   867 |       1 |
|   866 |       1 |
|   861 |       1 |
|   859 |       1 |
|   858 |       1 |
|   857 |       1 |
|   856 |       1 |
|   855 |       1 |
|   854 |       1 |
|   851 |       1 |
|   850 |       2 |
|   849 |       1 |
|   846 |       2 |
|   844 |       1 |
|   842 |       2 |
|   838 |       1 |
|   836 |       2 |
|   835 |       3 |
|   834 |       1 |
|   832 |       1 |
|   831 |       2 |
|   830 |       1 |
|   829 |       2 |
|   828 |       3 |
|   827 |       2 |
|   826 |       2 |
|   825 |       1 |
|   824 |       1 |
|   823 |       1 |
|   820 |       1 |
|   819 |       1 |
|   817 |       1 |
|   816 |       1 |
|   815 |       1 |
|   814 |       2 |
|   813 |       1 |
|   811 |       1 |
|   808 |       2 |
|   806 |       1 |
|   802 |       1 |
|   801 |       1 |
|   799 |       2 |
|   798 |       2 |
|   797 |       2 |
|   796 |       1 |
|   795 |       1 |
|   790 |       2 |
|   788 |       1 |
|   787 |       1 |
|   786 |       2 |
|   785 |       3 |
|   781 |       1 |
|   780 |       1 |
|   777 |       2 |
|   776 |       2 |
|   773 |       1 |
|   771 |       2 |
|   770 |       1 |
|   769 |       1 |
|   765 |       1 |
|   764 |       2 |
|   763 |       1 |
|   762 |       2 |
|   761 |       2 |
|   760 |       2 |
|   759 |       1 |
|   758 |       2 |
|   757 |       1 |
|   756 |       1 |
|   751 |       3 |
|   742 |       1 |
|   741 |       2 |
|   740 |       1 |
|   739 |       2 |
|   738 |       2 |
|   736 |       1 |
|   735 |       1 |
|   734 |       2 |
|   733 |       1 |
|   732 |       1 |
|   730 |       1 |
|   729 |       1 |
|   728 |       1 |
|   727 |       1 |
|   726 |       1 |
|   724 |       1 |
|   722 |       1 |
|   720 |       1 |
|   718 |       2 |
|   717 |       2 |
|   716 |       1 |
|   714 |       2 |
|   713 |       1 |
|   710 |       1 |
|   709 |       1 |
|   708 |       1 |
|   707 |       2 |
|   706 |       5 |
|   705 |       1 |
|   704 |       5 |
|   702 |       1 |
|   698 |       2 |
|   694 |       2 |
|   693 |       1 |
|   692 |       1 |
|   691 |       1 |
|   690 |       1 |
|   689 |       1 |
|   687 |       1 |
|   686 |       3 |
|   685 |       3 |
|   681 |       1 |
|   680 |       5 |
|   679 |       1 |
|   677 |       2 |
|   676 |       2 |
|   675 |       1 |
|   673 |       4 |
|   671 |       2 |
|   670 |       1 |
|   668 |       3 |
|   667 |       1 |
|   665 |       3 |
|   664 |       4 |
|   663 |       1 |
|   662 |       2 |
|   661 |       1 |
|   660 |       1 |
|   659 |       1 |
|   657 |       1 |
|   656 |       4 |
|   655 |       2 |
|   654 |       1 |
|   652 |       1 |
|   651 |       2 |
|   650 |       3 |
|   649 |       4 |
|   648 |       1 |
|   647 |       3 |
|   645 |       3 |
|   642 |       2 |
|   641 |       1 |
|   639 |       1 |
|   638 |       1 |
|   637 |       1 |
|   636 |       1 |
|   635 |       4 |
|   634 |       1 |
|   633 |       4 |
|   632 |       1 |
|   631 |       1 |
|   630 |       2 |
|   628 |       1 |
|   627 |       1 |
|   626 |       1 |
|   625 |       1 |
|   624 |       1 |
|   623 |       1 |
|   621 |       1 |
|   620 |       1 |
|   619 |       1 |
|   618 |       5 |
|   617 |       2 |
|   616 |       2 |
|   615 |       4 |
|   614 |       1 |
|   612 |       2 |
|   611 |       1 |
|   610 |       1 |
|   608 |       1 |
|   607 |       2 |
|   606 |       1 |
|   605 |       1 |
|   604 |       3 |
|   603 |       1 |
|   602 |       2 |
|   600 |       1 |
|   599 |       2 |
|   598 |       1 |
|   597 |       2 |
|   595 |       1 |
|   594 |       1 |
|   592 |       1 |
|   591 |       2 |
|   590 |       3 |
|   589 |       3 |
|   587 |       2 |
|   586 |       3 |
|   585 |       1 |
|   584 |       3 |
|   583 |       1 |
|   582 |       2 |
|   581 |       2 |
|   580 |       2 |
|   579 |       4 |
|   577 |       6 |
|   576 |       2 |
|   575 |       2 |
|   573 |       4 |
|   572 |       5 |
|   571 |       2 |
|   567 |       3 |
|   566 |       6 |
|   565 |       3 |
|   564 |       3 |
|   563 |       3 |
|   562 |       2 |
|   561 |       5 |
|   560 |       1 |
|   559 |       1 |
|   558 |       3 |
|   557 |       2 |
|   556 |       2 |
|   555 |       2 |
|   554 |       2 |
|   553 |       2 |
|   551 |       1 |
|   548 |       2 |
|   547 |       3 |
|   546 |       5 |
|   545 |       3 |
|   544 |       2 |
|   543 |       3 |
|   542 |       1 |
|   541 |       1 |
|   540 |       1 |
|   539 |       3 |
|   538 |       2 |
|   537 |       3 |
|   536 |       3 |
|   535 |       2 |
|   534 |       4 |
|   533 |       1 |
|   532 |       2 |
|   531 |       5 |
|   530 |       2 |
|   529 |       2 |
|   528 |       2 |
|   527 |       2 |
|   526 |       1 |
|   525 |       2 |
|   524 |       4 |
|   523 |       2 |
|   522 |       1 |
|   521 |       1 |
|   520 |       2 |
|   518 |       3 |
|   517 |       3 |
|   516 |       4 |
|   514 |       4 |
|   513 |       3 |
|   512 |       4 |
|   511 |       2 |
|   510 |       3 |
|   509 |       2 |
|   508 |       3 |
|   507 |       2 |
|   506 |       1 |
|   505 |       5 |
|   503 |       2 |
|   502 |       1 |
|   501 |       4 |
|   500 |       1 |
|   498 |       1 |
|   497 |       1 |
|   496 |       4 |
|   495 |       2 |
|   494 |       1 |
|   493 |       3 |
|   492 |       2 |
|   491 |       3 |
|   490 |       3 |
|   489 |       2 |
|   488 |       6 |
|   486 |       4 |
|   485 |       5 |
|   484 |       4 |
|   483 |       3 |
|   482 |       1 |
|   481 |       4 |
|   480 |       6 |
|   479 |       2 |
|   478 |       3 |
|   476 |       2 |
|   475 |       2 |
|   474 |       2 |
|   473 |       5 |
|   472 |       2 |
|   471 |       2 |
|   469 |       4 |
|   468 |       2 |
|   467 |       1 |
|   466 |       2 |
|   465 |       2 |
|   464 |       4 |
|   463 |       3 |
|   462 |       4 |
|   461 |       2 |
|   460 |       5 |
|   458 |       3 |
|   457 |       7 |
|   456 |       1 |
|   455 |       1 |
|   454 |       1 |
|   453 |       2 |
|   452 |       2 |
|   451 |       2 |
|   450 |       3 |
|   449 |       2 |
|   448 |       1 |
|   447 |       7 |
|   446 |       1 |
|   445 |       3 |
|   444 |       1 |
|   443 |       4 |
|   441 |       5 |
|   440 |       2 |
|   439 |       7 |
|   438 |       6 |
|   437 |       3 |
|   436 |       2 |
|   435 |       2 |
|   434 |       6 |
|   433 |       2 |
|   432 |       4 |
|   431 |       6 |
|   430 |       4 |
|   429 |       5 |
|   428 |       3 |
|   427 |       5 |
|   426 |       5 |
|   425 |       6 |
|   424 |       3 |
|   423 |       7 |
|   422 |       5 |
|   421 |       5 |
|   420 |       3 |
|   419 |       6 |
|   418 |       1 |
|   417 |       2 |
|   416 |       6 |
|   415 |       9 |
|   414 |       8 |
|   413 |       4 |
|   412 |       4 |
|   411 |       7 |
|   410 |       1 |
|   409 |       4 |
|   408 |       1 |
|   407 |       5 |
|   406 |       5 |
|   405 |       8 |
|   404 |       5 |
|   403 |       4 |
|   402 |       6 |
|   401 |       3 |
|   400 |       6 |
|   399 |       6 |
|   398 |       6 |
|   397 |       5 |
|   396 |       5 |
|   395 |       9 |
|   394 |       5 |
|   393 |       4 |
|   392 |       4 |
|   391 |       5 |
|   390 |       5 |
|   389 |       4 |
|   388 |       8 |
|   387 |       9 |
|   386 |       4 |
|   385 |       5 |
|   384 |       7 |
|   383 |       7 |
|   382 |      10 |
|   381 |       4 |
|   380 |       3 |
|   379 |       5 |
|   378 |       5 |
|   377 |       4 |
|   376 |       4 |
|   375 |       2 |
|   374 |       3 |
|   373 |       3 |
|   372 |       3 |
|   371 |       4 |
|   370 |       4 |
|   369 |       3 |
|   368 |       3 |
|   367 |       2 |
|   366 |       7 |
|   365 |      12 |
|   364 |       6 |
|   363 |       4 |
|   362 |       8 |
|   361 |       5 |
|   360 |       6 |
|   359 |       8 |
|   358 |       8 |
|   357 |       4 |
|   356 |       5 |
|   355 |       4 |
|   354 |       4 |
|   353 |       8 |
|   352 |       6 |
|   351 |       6 |
|   350 |       4 |
|   349 |       6 |
|   348 |      11 |
|   347 |      10 |
|   346 |       6 |
|   345 |       7 |
|   344 |       8 |
|   343 |      10 |
|   342 |       8 |
|   341 |       1 |
|   340 |      11 |
|   339 |       7 |
|   338 |      10 |
|   337 |       9 |
|   336 |       8 |
|   335 |       9 |
|   334 |       8 |
|   333 |      11 |
|   332 |       7 |
|   331 |       7 |
|   330 |       9 |
|   329 |       5 |
|   328 |       6 |
|   327 |       5 |
|   326 |      10 |
|   325 |      12 |
|   324 |       7 |
|   323 |       5 |
|   322 |      11 |
|   321 |      10 |
|   320 |      11 |
|   319 |      12 |
|   318 |       7 |
|   317 |      10 |
|   316 |       6 |
|   315 |      10 |
|   314 |       6 |
|   313 |      10 |
|   312 |      12 |
|   311 |       9 |
|   310 |       6 |
|   309 |      14 |
|   308 |      12 |
|   307 |       8 |
|   306 |       3 |
|   305 |      10 |
|   304 |      15 |
|   303 |       7 |
|   302 |      12 |
|   301 |       7 |
|   300 |      13 |
|   299 |      11 |
|   298 |      10 |
|   297 |      12 |
|   296 |      11 |
|   295 |      14 |
|   294 |      10 |
|   293 |       6 |
|   292 |      11 |
|   291 |      16 |
|   290 |      12 |
|   289 |       4 |
|   288 |       6 |
|   287 |      10 |
|   286 |       9 |
|   285 |      11 |
|   284 |      13 |
|   283 |      21 |
|   282 |       8 |
|   281 |      13 |
|   280 |      10 |
|   279 |      14 |
|   278 |      10 |
|   277 |      17 |
|   276 |      10 |
|   275 |      13 |
|   274 |      15 |
|   273 |      13 |
|   272 |       9 |
|   271 |      15 |
|   270 |      17 |
|   269 |      22 |
|   268 |      24 |
|   267 |      10 |
|   266 |      10 |
|   265 |       7 |
|   264 |      13 |
|   263 |      24 |
|   262 |      15 |
|   261 |      15 |
|   260 |      11 |
|   259 |       7 |
|   258 |      19 |
|   257 |      19 |
|   256 |      25 |
|   255 |      22 |
|   254 |      14 |
|   253 |      19 |
|   252 |      14 |
|   251 |      13 |
|   250 |       9 |
|   249 |      11 |
|   248 |      21 |
|   247 |      23 |
|   246 |      17 |
|   245 |      17 |
|   244 |      14 |
|   243 |      16 |
|   242 |      21 |
|   241 |      28 |
|   240 |      18 |
|   239 |      18 |
|   238 |      17 |
|   237 |      25 |
|   236 |      18 |
|   235 |      29 |
|   234 |      16 |
|   233 |      28 |
|   232 |      15 |
|   231 |      14 |
|   230 |      23 |
|   229 |      18 |
|   228 |      15 |
|   227 |      20 |
|   226 |      23 |
|   225 |      10 |
|   224 |      21 |
|   223 |      20 |
|   222 |      23 |
|   221 |      18 |
|   220 |      24 |
|   219 |      22 |
|   218 |      17 |
|   217 |      22 |
|   216 |      22 |
|   215 |      24 |
|   214 |      19 |
|   213 |      24 |
|   212 |      28 |
|   211 |      27 |
|   210 |      27 |
|   209 |      22 |
|   208 |      26 |
|   207 |      26 |
|   206 |      24 |
|   205 |      26 |
|   204 |      33 |
|   203 |      27 |
|   202 |      22 |
|   201 |      19 |
|   200 |      30 |
|   199 |      23 |
|   198 |      34 |
|   197 |      19 |
|   196 |      17 |
|   195 |      38 |
|   194 |      34 |
|   193 |      26 |
|   192 |      38 |
|   191 |      20 |
|   190 |      36 |
|   189 |      21 |
|   188 |      25 |
|   187 |      38 |
|   186 |      41 |
|   185 |      28 |
|   184 |      28 |
|   183 |      35 |
|   182 |      29 |
|   181 |      46 |
|   180 |      35 |
|   179 |      37 |
|   178 |      41 |
|   177 |      42 |
|   176 |      41 |
|   175 |      35 |
|   174 |      49 |
|   173 |      38 |
|   172 |      38 |
|   171 |      42 |
|   170 |      41 |
|   169 |      37 |
|   168 |      56 |
|   167 |      41 |
|   166 |      44 |
|   165 |      40 |
|   164 |      52 |
|   163 |      47 |
|   162 |      30 |
|   161 |      51 |
|   160 |      40 |
|   159 |      43 |
|   158 |      37 |
|   157 |      59 |
|   156 |      50 |
|   155 |      55 |
|   154 |      61 |
|   153 |      53 |
|   152 |      55 |
|   151 |      41 |
|   150 |      60 |
|   149 |      70 |
|   148 |      50 |
|   147 |      69 |
|   146 |      64 |
|   145 |      74 |
|   144 |      68 |
|   143 |      64 |
|   142 |      59 |
|   141 |      68 |
|   140 |      66 |
|   139 |      71 |
|   138 |      67 |
|   137 |      74 |
|   136 |      69 |
|   135 |      73 |
|   134 |      80 |
|   133 |      88 |
|   132 |      79 |
|   131 |      85 |
|   130 |      89 |
|   129 |      66 |
|   128 |      73 |
|   127 |     101 |
|   126 |      93 |
|   125 |      86 |
|   124 |      90 |
|   123 |     111 |
|   122 |      95 |
|   121 |     102 |
|   120 |     103 |
|   119 |     103 |
|   118 |     132 |
|   117 |     107 |
|   116 |     120 |
|   115 |     104 |
|   114 |     109 |
|   113 |      95 |
|   112 |     106 |
|   111 |     107 |
|   110 |     118 |
|   109 |     132 |
|   108 |     125 |
|   107 |     118 |
|   106 |     113 |
|   105 |     123 |
|   104 |     149 |
|   103 |     137 |
|   102 |     170 |
|   101 |     149 |
|   100 |     144 |
|    99 |     150 |
|    98 |     150 |
|    97 |     179 |
|    96 |     162 |
|    95 |     161 |
|    94 |     166 |
|    93 |     187 |
|    92 |     184 |
|    91 |     223 |
|    90 |     211 |
|    89 |     222 |
|    88 |     210 |
|    87 |     226 |
|    86 |     250 |
|    85 |     217 |
|    84 |     222 |
|    83 |     233 |
|    82 |     247 |
|    81 |     244 |
|    80 |     277 |
|    79 |     292 |
|    78 |     298 |
|    77 |     284 |
|    76 |     310 |
|    75 |     302 |
|    74 |     293 |
|    73 |     309 |
|    72 |     331 |
|    71 |     349 |
|    70 |     347 |
|    69 |     380 |
|    68 |     385 |
|    67 |     412 |
|    66 |     414 |
|    65 |     410 |
|    64 |     444 |
|    63 |     481 |
|    62 |     490 |
|    61 |     494 |
|    60 |     515 |
|    59 |     535 |
|    58 |     554 |
|    57 |     603 |
|    56 |     630 |
|    55 |     654 |
|    54 |     609 |
|    53 |     719 |
|    52 |     687 |
|    51 |     693 |
|    50 |     780 |
|    49 |     772 |
|    48 |     881 |
|    47 |     864 |
|    46 |     930 |
|    45 |    1027 |
|    44 |    1049 |
|    43 |    1104 |
|    42 |    1127 |
|    41 |    1270 |
|    40 |    1295 |
|    39 |    1315 |
|    38 |    1427 |
|    37 |    1588 |
|    36 |    1661 |
|    35 |    1740 |
|    34 |    1909 |
|    33 |    1949 |
|    32 |    2213 |
|    31 |    2455 |
|    30 |    2537 |
|    29 |    2644 |
|    28 |    3003 |
|    27 |    3198 |
|    26 |    3548 |
|    25 |    3792 |
|    24 |    4171 |
|    23 |    4720 |
|    22 |    5170 |
|    21 |    5729 |
|    20 |    6386 |
|    19 |    7333 |
|    18 |    8574 |
|    17 |    9364 |
|    16 |   11129 |
|    15 |   12903 |
|    14 |   14980 |
|    13 |   18195 |
|    12 |   21603 |
|    11 |   25772 |
|    10 |   32238 |
|     9 |   41074 |
|     8 |   55849 |
|     7 |   75156 |
|     6 |  108153 |
|     5 |  161732 |
|     4 |  267342 |
|     3 |  482478 |
|     2 |  972648 |
|     1 | 2153242 |
|     0 | 4677374 |
|    -1 |  304675 |
|    -2 |  120702 |
|    -3 |   57146 |
|    -4 |   30074 |
|    -5 |   15180 |
|    -6 |    7246 |
|    -7 |    3519 |
|    -8 |    1737 |
|    -9 |     746 |
|   -10 |     447 |
|   -11 |     274 |
|   -12 |     121 |
|   -13 |      91 |
|   -14 |      33 |
|   -15 |      25 |
|   -16 |      19 |
|   -17 |       3 |
|   -18 |      10 |
|   -19 |      11 |
|   -20 |       3 |
|   -21 |       3 |
|   -22 |       2 |
|   -23 |       1 |
|   -25 |       1 |
|   -26 |       5 |
|   -27 |       3 |
|   -29 |       1 |
|   -30 |       2 |
|   -31 |       2 |
|   -33 |       1 |
|   -35 |       2 |
|   -39 |       1 |
|   -43 |       1 |
|   -74 |       1 |
|  -106 |       1 |
|  -147 |       1 |
+-------+---------+
```

Some notable posts:

- Highest scoring post: [Why is processing a sorted array faster than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)
- Lowest scoring (currently not deleted, but closed) post: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly).  It's a php post...

Comment: And what is the winning post?

Comment: I want to see that -147 is.

Comment: @NathanOliver Looks like -147 and -106 have been deleted since SEDE was last updated. [-74](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3455660/1288) is locked in place though.

Comment: @BilltheLizard really?  I can see the -147.  It was also undeleted.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. I can follow the link to it, but it's not showing up on the [lowest-voted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=196336&sort=votes) page for me.

Comment: [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11022/295117) has data for the top most and lower scoring questions.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Historically locked questions don't show up on the question lists.

Comment: The last page is a moving target. The lowest questions keep getting pushed back by new questions coming in. Threw me off at first too. :)

Comment: @Mysticial Aha, that explains it!

Comment: Added a chart as another answer

Answer (score 2):

So, here's a chart based on @ryanyuyu's answer:

[image]

(log scale of course).

For every answer with non-zero score, there's about one answer with score 0. However, for every two answers with score 1 there's an answer with score at least 5. Surprising! ... maybe question and answer ages have something to do with this.